# Accessing attributes in a method - Do I pass it as parameter or do I use direct access via self?

Tags: python

I am new to python and especially OOP and I was wondering what would be the correct way (if there is one) of using attributes to calculate other attributes via methods.

Which version of the following would be considered good/bad and why?

```
# Version 1 - direct access to class attributes
class CubicSpline:

    def __init__(self, control_points):
        self.control_points = control_points
        self.polynomials = self.get_polynomials(self.control_points)

    def get_polynomials(self, control_points):

        polynomials = some_function_that_processes(control_points)

        return polynomials

# Version 2 - passing attributes as parameters
class CubicSpline:

    def __init__(self, control_points):
        self.control_points = control_points
        self.polynomials = self.get_polynomials()

    def get_polynomials(self):

        polynomials = some_function_that_processes(self.control_points)

        return polynomials
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend calculating only when you have to:

```
class CubicSpline:

    def __init__(self, control_points):
        self.control_points = control_points

    def get_polynomials(self):
        return some_function_that_processes(self.control_points)
```

There is no 'golden rule' that I know about. Expose the attribute when you see fit and expose a method when the attribute is redundant.
'When you see fit' comes to you with the experience.

I recommend reading [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles for OOP.

EDIT

You should prefer accessing attributes via self when possible. The method some_function_that_processes seems to be external so it cannot access 'self'.

No need to allocate more space for function parameters on the stack and code is more readable.

Comment: So do I save memory or gain speed if I use Version 2 compared to Version 1? My application will most likely have to be optimized in the (far) future, but I would like to make the code efficient with regards to memory usage and speed.

Comment: Though the difference is not too great it is better practice and will have effect if used across the application. Version 2 is better in means of memory and speed, you have to allocate space for the parameter and copy the value if you pass it as parameter